# how to display the ng-cordova camera inkove image in placeholder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

i have 6 product name and image in server which i am able to display in UI. here the UI is good but my requirement is to display the image take(base64 string) into the respected placeholder for temporary

```
<ul class="list">

           <li class="item" ng-repeat="i in products track by $index" ui-sref="leadProduct" >
                {{i}}
                <br>
                <br>
                <img ng-show="base64Array[$index] != undefined" ng-src="{{'data:image/png;base64,'+base64Array[$index]+imgURI}}" ng-err-src="http://placehold.it/100x100" ng-click="takePicture($index)">
                <img ng-show="base64Array[$index] == undefined" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" ng-click="takePicture($index)">
            </li>
        </ul>
```

this is how i am used to display form the array but my ng-cordova camera function is given belove.

```
$scope.takePicture = function() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 75,
        targetWidth: 100,
        targetHeight: 100,
        destinationType: 0
    });

    function onSuccess(imageData) {
        console.log('success 1');
        $scope.imgURI = imageData;
        console.log('success 2');
        $scope.$apply();
    }

    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
};
```

here i am able to invoke my camera function but i am not able to view the image that i taken from camera

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
<img ng-show="base64Array[$index] != undefined" ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{base64Array[$index]+imgURI}}" ng-err-src="http://placehold.it/100x100" ng-click="takePicture($index)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just dropped by and saw this. If you still want to find a solution here's what I have and it works for me through Ionic View.

```
//HTML
<ion-content ng-controller="someController">
      <img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}" alt="This is not working">
      <img ng-show="imgURI === undefined" ng-src="placeholder" alt="This is not working">
      <button class="button" ng-click="takePicture()" name="button">Take a Picture</button>
  </ion-content>


  //Controller
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
$scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}, function(err) {
});
```

You don't really need the "ALT" to the images but I like to add it.